# Angular Service as application state new object or update current object

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to create a service that will curry the application state in an object, so it sets and gets the application state object.

I don't know Redux, I find it confusing so I'm trying to create a simple alternative that kind-of mimics it, in a very light way.

I'm currently just updating the changes of the object and not creating a new object.

This is the update method in the service:

```
updateState(key: string, value: any, persist: boolean = false) {
    this.appState[key] = this.appState[key] ? {...this.appState[key], ...value} : value;
    this.state$.next(this.appState);
    if (persist) {
      if (typeof value === 'object') {
        localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
      } else {
        localStorage[key] = value;
      }
    }
  }
```

My question is ... Does Redux update current object values or creates a whole new object when a change is made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reducers are supposed to be pure functions (functions without any side effects). so they must not make changes in an existing state object, but create a new one. 
https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions

Comment: Does the state / object history get saved in Redux or are old changes wiped out?